# Is a direct function call and a self::function call always the same in rust?

Tags: rust, module

Recently, I started to learn rust. I'm currently at section 7.4 (bringing paths into scope). Tried hard, but I can't understand the purpose of `self::some_sort_of_identifier` in rust. Would you please explain what is the difference between `use self::module_name::function_name` and `use module_name::function_name`? I tried both and they both worked as expected in the example below:

```rust
mod my_mod {
    pub fn func() {
        print!("I'm here!");
    }
}

use my_mod::func;

fn main() {
    func();
}
```

Running this program, as expected, I can see this statement printed into the terminal:

```
I'm here
```

And this program here gives me exactly the same results and the rust compiler doesn't complain about anything:

```rust
mod my_mod {
    pub fn func() {
        print!("I'm here!");
    }
}

use self::my_mod::func;

fn main() {
    func();
}
```

So, is `self::` useless in rust? Why should I even use `self::my_mod::my_function();` when I can directly call it like so: `my_mod::my_function();`.

Are there any cases in which they might defer?

Comment: usually in macros you need to call stuff with fully paths so things doesn't mix up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your use-case, it's mainly a relict from the 2015 rust edition.
In this edition the following code would not compile:

```rust
use my_mod::func;

mod my_mod {
    use my_mod2::func2;
    pub fn func() {
        func2();
    }

    mod my_mod2 {
        pub fn func2() {
            print!("I'm here!");
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    func();
}
```

The compiler complains:

> error[E0432]: unresolved import `my_mod2`
> --> src\main.rs:4:9
> |
> |     use my_mod2::func2;
> |         ^^^^^^^ help: a similar path exists: `self::my_mod2`

Why did it change? You can see the note about the path and module system changes [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/path-changes.html).

> Rust 2018 simplifies and unifies path handling compared to Rust 2015. In Rust
> 2015, paths work differently in use declarations than they do
> elsewhere. In particular, **paths in use declarations would always start
> from the crate root**, while paths in other code implicitly started from
> the current scope. Those differences didn't have any effect in the
> top-level module, which meant that everything would seem
> straightforward until working on a project large enough to have
> submodules.
>
> In Rust 2018, paths in use declarations and in other code work the
> same way, both in the top-level module and in any submodule. You can
> use a relative path from the current scope, a path starting from an
> external crate name, or a path starting with crate, super, or self.

The blog post [Anchored and Uniform Paths](https://boats.gitlab.io/blog/post/anchored-uniform/) from the language team also underlines this

> The uniformity is a really big advantage, and the specific feature we’re changing -
> no longer having to use `self::` - is something I know is a big
> stumbling block for new users and a big annoyance for advanced users
> (I’m always having to edit and recompile because I tried to import
> from a submodule without using self).

The keyword itself however is still useful in `use` statments to refer to the current module in the path itself. Like

`use std::io::{self, Read};`

being the same as

```
use std::io;
use std::io::Read;
```